# É possível adicionar um código php num arquivo .js?

Tags: php, javascript

Bom a minha pergunta é se é possível adicionar um código

Se não, como posso fazer para ser possível.

Obrigado

Comment: Bom, no caso é ao contrário quero escrever php, num código javascript.

Comment: Se o ARQUIVO for .php, você consegue incluir um codigo php dentro do código js... mas se o arquivo for js... não.

Comment: Então, não tem como né? Tenho que passar o js, para o arquivo.php certo?

Comment: certo... acho que é a única forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renomeie o arquivo .js para .php, após isso, no início do arquivo, adicione o seguinte.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
```

Agora você pode incluir códigos PHP tanto dentro dessas tags que criamos, como em qualquer outra parte do arquivo, lembrando de seguir as regras básicas do PHP.

Esse arquivo irá passar pelo interpretador do PHP antes de ser enviado pro cliente (como acontece com um arquivo .php com HTML, por exemplo), e quando chegar no cliente, será um arquivo .js comum.